# accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused doesn't get called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I´m trying to get the information if an element get focused with voiceover. So I override the `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused` method, but this gets never called. Did I forget something?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    viewArray.append(UIView())
    viewArray.append(UIView())        
    viewArray[0].frame = CGRectMake(20, 210, 100, 100)
    viewArray[0].isAccessibilityElement = true
    self.view.addSubview(viewArray[0])

    viewArray[1].frame = CGRectMake(220, 220, 100, 100)
    viewArray[1].isAccessibilityElement = true
    self.view.addSubview(viewArray[1])

}

//never called
override func accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused(){
    println("accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It's not being called because your view controller is not an accessibility element. You should override it in the custom view subclass.

Just to clarify: you won't get that callback whenever an accessibility element becomes focused, but instead the element itself will get that callback when *it* becomes forces.

The reason why you can override it (the reason why UIViewController implements it) is that it's an informal protocol, a category implemented on NSObject, meaning that every NSObject implements those methods.

Answer (score 0):

**accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused** is not calling, Because where you are adding subviews, that class **isAccessibilityElement** is false. If you want to access the **accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused** for subview. You can create the custom class and call this func.

You can check this link for more details about accessibilities: https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html